# resolve artifacts from artifact properties using gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve dependencies from their properties using artifactory and gradle but it's unclear from [the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution).

I have a large build that needs to resolve thousands of artifacts where no versions are declared in the build.gradle files. We have the [Netflix dependency recommender plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-dependency-recommender-plugin) working for most of our use cases, but I'm still trying to figure it out for this last scenario using properties.

The artifacts we're dealing with are typically Ivy and are fairly standard looking, such as this:

```
{
  "repo" : "some_repo",
  "path" : "/some_group/some_name/1.1.0-integration",
  "created" : "2017-06-19T10:21:55.765+02:00",
  "createdBy" : "lebowski",
  "lastModified" : "2017-06-19T10:21:55.765+02:00",
  "modifiedBy" : "leboswki",
  "lastUpdated" : "2017-06-19T10:21:55.765+02:00",
  "children" : [ {
    "uri" : "/some_file-1.1.0-integration.jar",
    "folder" : false
  }, {
    "uri" : "/some_file-tests-1.1.0-integration.jar",
    "folder" : false
  }, {
    "uri" : "/ivy-1.1.0-integration.xml",
    "folder" : false
  } ],
  "uri" : "http://artifactory.url.com:8081/artifactory/api/storage/some_repo/some_group/some_name/1.1.0-integration"
}
```

There are multiple versions of some_group/some_name always with a version number in the format: x.y.z-integration

However, at any point in time we need to know what is "latest" (i.e. head of the integration branch) so we use a property on the folder some_group/some_name such as this:

```
{
  "properties" : {
  "integration" : [ "1.1.0-integration" ]
  },
  "uri" : "http://artifactory.url.com:8081/artifactory/api/storage/some_repo/some_group/some_name"
}
```

Where the key is "integration" with value "1.1.0-integration". The value is updated with a new version published to artifactory each time we have pull request merged to the integration branch.

While I can do plain HTTP GET against the API to find the value I wanted to try and test out resolving artifacts from their properties.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this in a build.gradle file?